# Beautiful Soup can't find comment

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use bs4 to scrape a page but key to my objective is finding a comment in the page.

I cannot make bs4 find it. Can you help. This is my code:

```
        # Parse the HTML content with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find the first comment that starts with "<!-- a -->"
    start_comment = soup.find(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and "<!-- a -->" in text)
```

The comment is in the text of the html just like this is but my code is unable to find the comment for <!-- a -->:

```
<h4>Some Heading</h4>

<!-- a -->
```

Can anyone see why bs4 is just breezing on by this comment even though I am specifically searching for it please? Is there another operator I should be using here...

Answer (score 0):

The `text` passed to the lambda function does not include the comment tags, so you're checking for something like `"<!-- a -->" in " a "` which is clearly false.

Your comment says you want comments starting with `a`, so something like

```
lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and text.strip().startswith("a")
```

should work.